# What is the quotient set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let:
$$S = \{ \left\langle {x,y} \right\rangle |x - y \in \mathbb{Q} \} $$

Find $T$, the quotient set of $S$.

Well, I can tell for example the equivalence class of $\sqrt 2$ is:
$$[\sqrt 2 ] = \{ x|x - \sqrt 2  \in \mathbb{Q}\}  = \{ \sqrt 2  + q|q \in \mathbb{Q}\} $$

so, the cardinality $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\left| \mathbb{Q} \right|$

Using this information, how should $T$ be defined?

Comment: What are $\langle x,y\rangle$? Are they pairs of rational numbers? Of integers?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define $\Bbb{R/Q}$, but informally this set cannot be given a nice and explicit definition exception the most obvious one, which has a lot of repetitions $$\Bbb{R/Q}=\{[r]\mid r\in\Bbb R\}.$$

The reason is that for a nice definition we begin by taking a set of representatives, some $D$ such that every $r\in\Bbb R$ is equivalent to exactly one element of $D$, then we can write that $\Bbb{R/Q}=\{[d]\mid d\in D\}$. This is what we do in the case of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Or even in the case of $\Bbb{R/Z}$ where we can easily define the quotient.

However in the case of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ the set of representatives cannot be explicitly defined, and we need the axiom of choice to define it. It is consistent that in some models where the axiom of choice fails, such set of representatives does not exist for $\Bbb{R/Q}$. So any definition other than the one written above cannot be given explicitly in the general case.